# What is Queue Length Peak

Tags: .net, multithreading, debugging

[image]

I am looking at my application at the Process Explorer. Queue Peak Length has very high value.
Can anyone explain the meaning of this parameter.

Answer (score 11):

From MSDN [Lock and Thread Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf749bat.aspx):

> **Queue Length Peak** Displays the total number of threads that waited to acquire a managed lock since the application started.

However, I *suspect* it means "...total number of *times* any thread has waited to..." rather than the actual count of threads that have been and gone.

If that description is correct, then the naming is odd... I *expect* "peak" to mean "max" - i.e. "what is the longest the queue length has been" - but that does not appear to be what is described.

Comment: I checked in the debugger I have quite a few threads waiting on Wait so I assume you are right, this parameters represents the total number of times any thread has waited waited to acquire a managed lock since the application started.

Comment: @CaptainComic yes, but you currently have less than 40 threads; I suspect it is unlikely you have ever had 386438 threads at the same time.

Comment: @CaptainComic as I tried to describe, and as MSDN hints; the number of times threads have had to wait on a managed lock. Note: this does not necessarily mean a problem - it could be *entirely correct* to be doing this. For example, a highly active producer/consumer queue with a Pulse could (I'm guessing) cause this, **without even ever being contended** (if the consumer is waiting for a producer to put in work, or the producer is waiting for a consumer to process work to make space)